# ElasticSearch has_child query finds nothing

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have a problem, objects have been indexed but when searching with has_child, nothing is returned.

**The mapping:**

**Parent:**

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/article/_mapping?pretty'
"items" : {
    "mappings" : {
        "article" : {
            "_meta" : {
                "model" : "..."
            },
            "_source" : {
                "enabled" : false,
                "includes" : [ ],
                "excludes" : [ ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "content" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "store" : true,
                    "analyzer" : "app_standard",
                    "fields" : {
                        "transliterated" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "analyzer" : "transliteration"
                        },
                        "stemmed" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "analyzer" : "app_text_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
                ,...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/comment/_mapping?pretty'
"items" : {
    "mappings" : {
        "comment" : {
            "_meta" : {
                "model" : "..."
            },
            "_parent" : {
                "type" : "article"
            },
            "_routing" : {
                "required" : true,
                "path" : "article_id"
            },
            "_source" : {
                "enabled" : false,
                "includes" : [ ],
                "excludes" : [ ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "article_id" : {
                    "type" : "long",
                    "store" : true
                }
                ,...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both parent and child documents exist:

Parent:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/article/110700879894'
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "items",
  "_type": "article",
  "_id": "110700879894",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true
}
```

Child without routing fails:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/comment/110700879894.110700879894'
```

result:

```
{
  "error": "RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [items]/[comment]/[110700879894.110700879894]]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Child with routing:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/comment/110700879894.110700879894?parent=110700879894'
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "items",
  "_type": "comment",
  "_id": "110700879894.110700879894",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true
}
```

But has_child finds nothing:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/article/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "comment",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "article_id": "110700879894"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

has_parent too:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/items/comment/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "article",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 232,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

My guess is that there was something fishy in indexing, parent-child relation was not set. But in the other hand, child was found with correct routing.

Or am I simply doing the query wrong.

How can I check what are the child documents of a parent?

**Edit**

Indexing request:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"items","_type":"comment","_id":"110700879894.110700879894"}}
{"article_id":"110700879894",...}
```

Shouldnt here be parent or something?

Comment: You do indeed need to specify parent when indexing

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html):

" By default `_id` is not indexed and not stored (thus, not created)."

Comment: Ok, correct point but still no luck (I edited the has_child and has_parent queries in the original post). I guess if has_parent match_all returns nothing then it is indexing problem and I should check that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with FOSElasticaBundle. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/types.md#parent-fields states that _parent should be separate from "mappings", but Transformer did not receive _parent definition. See also https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/pull/665.

I guess quickest way would be copying _parent under mappings section as well (can't be 100% sure because I have written my own Transformer). Also ModelToElasticaAutoTransformer does some weird things on setting child documents parent - gets childs **parent_id** field, expecting it to be **parent object**, then gets its id, using **child's** identifier setting. I think its buggy :)

```
if ($key == '_parent') {
        $property = (null !== $mapping['property'])?$mapping['property']:$mapping['type'];
        $value = $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($object, $property);
        $document->setParent($this->propertyAccessor->getValue($value, $mapping['identifier']));
        continue;
}
```

Comment: I tried copying _parent under the mappings section and it didn't work. I think this might be legacy code that may not be relevant any more. I know this is the approach in FOQElastica but not in FOSElastica. Like John I had to use a custom Transformer